# How do I call a function after a redirect or refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        window.location.replace("searchscreen.html");
            var term = $('#search').text();
            displaySearchEntries(term); 


        });
```

I am writing code to direct to a search results page and to call the javascript function to return the appropriate results.  As of now, this redirects the page, and displaySearchEntries(term) gets called, but disappears immediately.  It seems as if the redirect happens after the call to the function, but I don't know why that would be happening or how to prevent it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you gotta call displaySearch function after the searchscreen is loaded..
U gotta call this function on load of search screen

Comment: I tried putting it inside $(document).ready() but that didn't seem to make a difference.  Should onLoad() be different?

edit: I tried putting display() inside onLoad= and it didn't change anything.

Comment: .ready or on load doesn't matter..
but the script containing the function dipslayEntries must be present in the search screen page..
pass term as a query string to searchscreen.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not control the next page. Once the redirect happens, that page is done.

If you want something to happen on the next page you will need to find a way to pass info to that page. That is normally done with a querystring, posting a form, cookies, or local storage. The next page would need to look for that data and process it.

---

**Basic idea using querystring:**

First page:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var term = $('#search').text();
    window.location.replace("searchscreen.html?search=" + encodeUriComponent(term));
});
```

and code on the searchscreen.html

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(function(){   
    //read querystring
    var term = getParameterByName("search");
    //run your search
    if(term.length) {
        displaySearchEntries(term);
    }
});
```

Comment: Then how do I call a function once the new page loads?

Comment: You would have to have an onload handler on that new page. There is NO WAY to do it from the page that calls the next.

Comment: I think with the newer [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), this would be feasible .. but not with a general location.replace or navigation.

Comment: Is it possible to use POST with just javascript?

Comment: Could you please explain what replace is doing there?  Why do you need to replace those characters?

Comment: That is not my code, but it is escaping any [ and ] in the parameter name so when it builds the regular expression, it works correct

Answer (score 0):

Call function on the redirected page.In search screen.html use document.ready

Answer (score 0):

When you use window.location it kills all the scripts running in the browser. You can use JQuery AJAX call and use the callback function to do the rest.

If you don't won't to use the AJAX function the only possible way to do this is use a parameter to identify the redirection.

```
window.location = "searchscreen.html?redirect=true";
```

And check the redirect variable and call the function in the $(document).ready().